# (Blender 2.82.1) "Could not build proxy for strip ..." How do I fix this?

Tags: error, proxies

I'm using Blender 2.82.1 on windows. When I add a video and try to rebuild its proxy and timecode at 50%, I receive an error message "Could not build proxy for strip ..." This was not a problem before. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling blender, but didn't work. How do I fix this?

Comment: Same here, no explanation, just "can't do it" I tried to re-encode the clip just for kicks, but no ; looks like proxies are broken :(

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with the following file: "30 ans laura.mp4"

I renamed the original file to: "Laura.mp4", reimported it and it worked.
I suppose it's an issue with the numbers.

I didn't investigate further but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar-ish problem when building a proxy that I'd already made but wasn't working.

To solve it I deleted the proxy folder (where blender keeps its proxies) in the video source folder (where the clip was) and now it works.

Maybe Blender is already seeing a proxy with that file name somewhere in your system and that's causing a problem, and also why renaming the file worked for the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me and may be helpful for others too https://www.blendernation.com/2020/05/30/edit-4k-video-using-blenders-vse/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/147572)